# UNION ALL query missing data?

Tags: mysql

Using UNION ALL to get results from two queries but it is losing a row of data. If I switch which select statement comes first the missing data switches to a different row. I know each slect statement pulls correct information when ran seperate but when put together not working correctly. The following is my query:

```
SELECT YEAR( orderDate ) AS "SalesYear"
     , MONTH( orderDate ) AS "SalesMonth"
     , SUM( orderTotal ) AS "TotalSales"
     , orderDetails.productID 
FROM orders
INNER JOIN orderdetails 
   ON orders.orderID = orderDetails.orderID
INNER JOIN products
   ON orderDetails.productID = products.productID

UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR( orderDate ) AS "SalesYear"
     , MONTH( orderDate ) AS "SalesMonth"
     , SUM( orderTotal ) AS "TotalSales"
     , instorepurchasedetails.productID 
FROM in_storepurchase
INNER JOIN instorepurchasedetails 
   ON in_storepurchase.isPurchaseID = instorepurchasedetails.isPurchaseID
INNER JOIN products
   ON instorepurchasedetails.productID = products.productID
GROUP BY YEAR(orderDate ), MONTH( orderDate ), orderTotal, productID
```

Any ideas why this is happening and what I can do?

Comment: some of the orderTotals are not adding up right either

Comment: In your second query, why are you including a `GROUP BY orderTotal`?  You have an aggregate function on that column so I do not understand the grouping.

Comment: default behavior of UNION is to eliminate duplicate rows. Possible explanation? See also UNION ALL.

Comment: @Tim They are using `UNION ALL` so duplicate will not be eliminated.

Comment: I just tried adding orderTotals to see if I would get my missing results.

Comment: @Bluefeet: Just worth double checking the query to make sure :-)

Comment: Added group by clause to the first select statement and got all the right data. Thanks for your input.

Comment: ACtually the thats not working quite right either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to add a `GROUP BY` clause to each `SELECT` block, and specify the correct columns, something like this:

```
SELECT "SalesYear"
     , "SalesMonth"
     , SUM( "TotalSales" ) AS "TotalSales"
     , productID 
FROM (
   SELECT YEAR( orderDate ) AS "SalesYear"
        , MONTH( orderDate ) AS "SalesMonth"
        , SUM( orderTotal ) AS "TotalSales"
        , orderDetails.productID 
   FROM orders
   INNER JOIN orderdetails 
      ON orders.orderID = orderDetails.orderID
   INNER JOIN products
      ON orderDetails.productID = products.productID
   GROUP BY YEAR(orderDate ), MONTH( orderDate ), orderDetails.productID

   UNION ALL
   SELECT YEAR( orderDate ) AS "SalesYear"
        , MONTH( orderDate ) AS "SalesMonth"
        , SUM( orderTotal ) AS "TotalSales"
        , instorepurchasedetails.productID 
   FROM in_storepurchase
   INNER JOIN instorepurchasedetails 
      ON in_storepurchase.isPurchaseID = instorepurchasedetails.isPurchaseID
   INNER JOIN products
      ON instorepurchasedetails.productID = products.productID
   GROUP BY YEAR(orderDate), MONTH(orderDate), instorepurchasedetails.productID
   ) x
GROUP BY "SalesYear", "SalesMonth", productID
```

I also removed the **orderTotal** from the `GROUP BY` clause because I don't think that's what you needed.

**EDIT:** Updated based on OP comment.

Comment: The problem with this is that it lists all the data from first select statement in the group by order then the data from the second select statement  in the group order when some of the data from each set should be merged together.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you want now.  That's slightly different from your original question.  You just need to treat this as a "derived table".  I'll update the answer.

Comment: the outcome is showing sales year in all the sales year rows, salesmonth in all the sales month rows and zero in the totals columns and the productId is correct

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help more.  If you increase your "rep" score to 20 or above, we could continue a discussion in "chat".  I can help a little by upvoting your question. Perhaps someone else will see the question and make another suggestion.

Comment: I just gave you 10 rep points; you also earn rep by accepting questions.  Go back to the previous question you asked on this a "accept" one of the answers (click the green check-mark).

Comment: I was able to get it to work with a bit of alteration. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `x`.`SalesYear`, 
`x`.`SalesMonth`, 
SUM( `x`. `TotalSales`) AS "TotalSales", 
productID

FROM
(

     SELECT YEAR( orderDate ) AS "SalesYear", 
     MONTH( orderDate ) AS "SalesMonth", 
     SUM( orderTotal ) AS "TotalSales", 
     orderDetails.productID 
    FROM orders
    INNER JOIN orderdetails ON orders.orderID = orderDetails.orderID
    INNER JOIN products ON orderDetails.productID = products.productID
    GROUP BY YEAR(orderDate ) , MONTH( orderDate ), productID 

UNION ALL

     SELECT YEAR( orderDate ) AS "SalesYear", 
     MONTH( orderDate ) AS "SalesMonth", 
     SUM( orderTotal ) AS "TotalSales", 
     instorepurchasedetails.productID 
    FROM in_storepurchase
    INNER JOIN instorepurchasedetails ON in_storepurchase.isPurchaseID =                       instorepurchasedetails.isPurchaseID
    INNER JOIN products ON instorepurchasedetails.productID = products.productID
    GROUP BY YEAR(orderDate ) , MONTH( orderDate ), productID 
) x
     GROUP BY  `x`.`SalesMonth`, productID 
     ORDER BY `x`.`SalesMonth` ASC
```